# Trocar campo de hidden para text com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tudo bom pessoal ?

Então, eu tenho um campo do tipo hidden, eu preciso atribuir um valor a ele e trocar ele de hidden pra pra text após o calculo

```
function calc(){
    var myVar = formCalc.myCamp.value;
    document.getElementById("calcFeito").value = myVar*2;
    document.getElementsByTagName("hidden").setAttribute("type", "text");
}   


<form name="formCalc">
    <br>Digite o Valor:<br>
    <input type="text" name="myCalc">
    <input type="button" value="botão" onClick="calc()"></button><br>
</form>
<input type='hidden' id='calcFeito'>
```

Comment: Boa noite, falta algo na resposta? Ela resolveu o seu problema?

Comment: Tinha esquecido de marcar como certo, desculpe, corrigi la @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Imagina, eu fico grato :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função `document.getElementsByTagName` não é usada pra buscar por atributos, recomendo que leia a documentação, o uso esta totalmente errôneo, essa função busca por nome de tag, se quiser pegar elementos de forma mais facil pode usar o `document.querySelector`, ou até mesmo o `document.getElementById`.

Também conforme citou o MagicHat, as tags estão incorretas, tem um `</button>` sobrando, procure sempre fazer a marcação o mais correto possível, pode usar ferramentas como:

- https://validator.w3.org

> **Nota:** não precisa validar 100%, se preocupe em olhar as validações sobre tags erradas e ids repetidas (outra coisa que pode causar problemas)

Veja aqui adaptei tudo pra `getElementById`:

```js
function calc(){
    var myVar = document.getElementById("myCalc").value;
    document.getElementById("calcFeito").value = myVar * 2;
    document.getElementById("calcFeito").setAttribute("type", "text");
}
```

```html
<form name="formCalc">
<br>Digite o Valor:<br>
<input type="text" name="myCalc" id="myCalc">
<input type="button" value="botão" onClick="calc()"><br>
</form>
<input type='hidden' id='calcFeito'>
```

**Leia a documentação** sobre DOM e aprenda como funciona cada função antes de usa-las:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Essa tag de fechamento button ai tá correta? Por curiosidade, nunca vi dessa forma...

Comment: @MagicHat não, obrigado por mencionar, foi o exemplo do AP que estava incorreto, acabei por copiar o erro.

Comment: @MagicHat pronto editei, obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer de duas formas usando o jQuery.

A primeira, você altera o `type=hidden`para `type=text` usando a função [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

Exemplo:

```
/*Para mostrar*/
$("#calcFeito").attr('type', 'text');

/*Para ocultar*/
$("#calcFeito").attr('type', 'hidden');
```

Ou usar o próprio `.show()` e `.hide()` do jQuery.

Tendo `<input type='text' id='calcFeito' style='display:none'>` como base:

```
/*Para mostrar*/
$("#calcFeito").show();

/*Para ocultar*/
$("#calcFeito").hide();
```