# metodo $.find() em javascript puro

Tags: javascript

Como definir o atributo de um elemento filho dentro de outro elemento usando `javascript` puro? 
em `jquery` seria: `$('.preview').find('img').attr('src','#url');`
mas como fica em `javascript` puro?

```
<div class="preview"><img src="" title=""/></div>

var el = document.getElementsByClassName("preview");
var img = el.getElementsByTagName('img');
img.setAttribute("src" , 'url');
```

tentei com a sua resposta mas não deu certo: no console aparece: 'indefinido'

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e){                   
    document.getElementsByClassName("preview")[0].querySelectorAll("img")[0].setAttribute("src", e.target.result);                      
};

reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
```

essa função é chamada no evento `change` do input file

o que estou tentando fazer é pegar a url da imagem que é carregada no input e mostra uma miniatura, o código funciona em `jquery` mas preciso fazer em `javascript`

dessa forma funciona:

```
<img src="" alt="" id="preview">

document.getElementById("preview").setAttribute('src', 'url');
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("preview")` esta errado, `document.getElementById` é para IDs e não CLASS, e outra coisa `document.getElementById` retorna apenas um elemento ou `null`, diferente de `getElementsByClassName` e `getElementsByTagName` que retornam multiplos elementos iteráveis.

Comment: eu sei eu estava testando e acabei trazendo errado para cá, de qualquer forma não funciona quando mudo para `class`

Comment: Tome cuidado ao usar a propriedade id, você não deve referenciar dois elementos com o mesmo id

Comment: eu sei, por isso preciso usar com `getElementsByClassName` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Eu respondi algo semelhante em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141203/3635, para ser mais claro o `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName` e `querySelectorAll` são diferentes em comportamento de `getElementById` e `querySelector` (sem o "All"):

- `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName` e `querySelectorAll` retornam uma lista de elementos, semelhante a um array, podendo retornar esta lista com zero itens
- `querySelector` retorna apenas um elemento baseado em um query que pode ser mais complexa, ou retorna `null` se nada encontrar
- `getElementById` retorna apenas um elemento pelo seu id, ou retorna `null` se nada encontrar. Ele só pode ser usado com elementos propriedade do tipo `Document` ou um `responseXML` por exemplo, mas **não irá funcionar** se usado em outros elementos como algo assim:

  ```html
  <div id="a">
     <div id="b">x</div>
  </div>
  <script>
     console.log(document.getElementById("a").getElementById("b"));
  </script>
  ```

No geral algo que resolve o seu problema é usar apenas `querySelector`:

```html
<div class="preview"><img src="" title=""/></div>

<script>
var img = document.querySelector(".preview > img");

//Verifica se encontrou o img
if (img) {
    img.setAttribute("src" , 'url');
}
</script>
```

Se houverem múltiplos `.preview`:

```html
<div class="preview"><img src="" title=""/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="" title=""/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="" title=""/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="" title=""/></div>
```

Então use `querySelectorAll` com `for`:

```javascript
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".preview > img");

for (var i = 0, j = imgs.length; i < j; i++) {
    imgs[i].setAttribute("src" , 'url');
}
```

**Leia a documentação** sobre DOM e aprenda como funciona cada função antes de usa-las:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: todas as formas aqui expostas para conseguir acessar o filho do elemento funcionaram, porem no momento de atribuição por algum motivo ele não atribui o valor da imagem ao valor do atributo `src`. no console ele imprime a imagem em formato `base64` mas não atribui ao `src` da imagem...

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16449483/3956218

Comment: @HebertdeLima mas você não mencionou isto na pergunta, esta falando do `FileReader`?

Comment: porque o problema não é o `FileReader`, é apenas como chegar até o filho do elemento e atribuir valor a ele com `setAtribute` o que ainda não deu certo. =)

Comment: só funciona se utilizo `getElementById` mas com `getElementsByClassName` não funciona isso que não entendo =\, e como preciso dessa mesma função em dois lugares não quero ter que escrever duas vezes pra fazer a mesma coisa

Comment: @HebertdeLima o problema é que você esta fazendo confusão, na tua pergunta não tem nada sobre `base64` eu só perguntei do FileReader para saber de onde vinha o tal base64. A sua pergunta esta vaga, ou seja não tem a tal informação sobre isto, não tem como responder de maneira concreta se vc não mostrar a parte que falhou.

Comment: Sobre `getElementById` mas com `getElementsByClassName` esta explicado na resposta, você entendeu errado como funciona ambos, `getElementsByClassName` não funciona porque ele pode retornar vários itens e talvez o item de numero `[0]` não seja o que você quer acessar. Por isto eu sugeri o `document.querySelector`. Entendeu? @HebertdeLima

Comment: sim, por sinal mudei no código, mas na hora do setAtribute ele retorna `undefined`

Comment: @HebertdeLima retorna undefined justamente devido ao que eu já disse e torno a repetir: `getElementsByClassName` não funciona porque ele pode retornar vários itens e talvez o item de numero [0] não seja o que você quer acessar.... Resumindo por `getElementsByClassName` retornar multiplos elementos pode ser que em tua página existam mais elementos HTML com a classe "preview" e ele acaba acessando o elemento errado, agora usando `querySelector(.preview > img)` ele só vai procurar o preview que tiver um img e ignorar os demais.

Answer (score 1):

## Com jquery

```js
var elemento = $('.preview').find('img').attr('src');
console.log(elemento);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview"><img src="teste" title=""/></div>
```

---

Note que funcionaria do mesmo modo se fizesse:

```js
var elemento = $('.preview img').attr('src');
console.log(elemento);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview"><img src="teste" title=""/></div>
```

## Com [vanillaJs](http://vanilla-js.com/)

```js
var elemento = document.querySelectorAll('.preview img')[0].getAttribute('src');
console.log(elemento);
```

```html
<div class="preview"><img src="teste" title="" /></div>
```

---

Para alterar o atributo bastaria usar o setAttribute

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.preview img')[0].getAttribute('src'));
document.querySelectorAll('.preview img')[0].setAttribute('src', "Ola");
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.preview img')[0].getAttribute('src'));
```

```html
<div class="preview"><img src="teste" title="" /></div>
```

Fonte: [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: Se vai usar `querySelectorAll` seria melhor usar em tudo, não vejo motivo para usar `getElementsByClassName` quando se usa `querySelector` e `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Não =) ... acho que vc confundiu, `>` indica "filho", ou seja em js puro teria que usar `childNodes` e "filtraria eles", não seria bem a mesma coisa.

Comment: nessa parte `.setAttribute('src', e.target.result)` ele retorna `undefined`, coloquei `console.log(e.target.result)` e ele me retorna a imagem em base64 `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA...`

Comment: Eu usaria: `document.querySelectorAll(".preview img")[0].setAttribute("src", e.target.result);`